# How to set up number of items in Excel activeX combobox?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

How to set up the number of items to display for an activeX combobox in Excel VBA? I try this code. No matter the number I set up in the second line there are always default 8 items, as the msgbox spits out.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ComboBox1.ListRows = 4 'This should work, but it does not
    MsgBox (ComboBox1.ListCount) 'It always equals 8
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Control object.. 
This code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193982.aspx

```
Dim ListControl As Control 
 Set ListControl = Forms!Customers!CustomerList 
 With ListControl 
   If .ListCount < 8 Then 
      .ListRows = .ListCount 
   Else 
     .ListRows = 8 
   End If 
 End With
```

The following code uses this logic and applies it to my Form (UserForm1) combo box (Combobox1). This in turn is attached to a button click event (CommanButton5). Change the number in the J loop to see the different number of rows that are displayed. Note: This will not alter the number of rows in the Combobox it simply limits the number of rows in the initial dropdown. You can only change the rows shown in the combobox by AddItem/RemoveItem!

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim j As Integer
For j = 0 To 10
  ComboBox1.AddItem j
Next
Me.Repaint

Dim ListControl As Control
 Set ListControl = UserForm1!ComboBox1
 With ListControl
   If .ListCount < 8 Then
       .ListRows = .ListCount
   Else
     .ListRows = 8
   End If
 End With
 Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

Note: You will not need the Me.Repaint if you are controlling this in the Form Initialize event

Comment: How is `Forms!Customers!` relevant to my `ComboBox1`?

Comment: It's just an example taken from Microsofts guide to combobox controls. Adapt as required! :-)

Comment: See edited changes to my original post. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as "coded".

`ComboBox1.ListCount` gives the amount of `Items` in your `List`

`ComboBox1.ListRows = 4` sets the value of the amount of `Items` you can see before you need to start scrolling.

If you want to change the amount of `Items` in your `List` you would have to alter the source or use `RemoveItem` method.

see: [List Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251418.aspx), [ListCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278753.aspx) and [ListRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251479.aspx)